# Query creates redundant entries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've been using MS Access 2010 for a while now and I have big problem. I'll attach a dummy database [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B38suP6Vp2TONmxhdm5oUGt4R28) for reference. It's simple, three tables: 2 for data and 1 to act as a junction for a many-to-many relationship. I have one query that I would like to be able to enter values. Lets say I enter the following:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|    NameA    |    NameB    |
+-------------+-------------+
|    Frank    |    Bob      |    
|    Frank    |    Harry    |
|    Tom      |    Harry    |
+-------------+-------------+
```

The 2 data tables will end up with **redundant entries**. It's as if the query simply adds a new entry regardless of what is already in the tables. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Per request here is the query code

```
SELECT Table1.NameA, Table2.NameB
FROM Table2 
INNER 
JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.IDA) 
ON Table2.ID = Table3.IDB;
```

Comment: Have you got an index? What is wrong with the entries you show?

Comment: Copy and paste the query text so we can see it without opening your accdb file. please!

Comment: This query is a `SELECT` query, not an `INSERT` query.  A select query will only return results, not add records.  Are you trying to write a query that will return results without duplicates?

Comment: I do not care how, but I want to be able to add records without duplicates. With what I have now (the SELECT query), it adds the records but ignores the fact that it is making duplicates. How would an INSERT query fix this problem?

Comment: If you have a unique index, it will not be possible to add duplicates.

Comment: I've tried changing the NameA field on Table1 and the NameB field on Table2 to unique indexes by going to Field Properties > Indexed > Yes (No Duplicates). This only halts the query when I try to add the entries. Basically, the query still tries to add duplicate entries. The query is dumb and not aware of its environment. I'm looking up sql semantics, but I'm thinking that the JET engine simply will not interperate the query as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer [here](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-do-i-add-value-to-combo-box-with.html).

The key points are as follows:

1. The builtin functionality provided to the query via DataSheet View is very
   simple. It only adds new records regardless of creating redundant
   entries.
2. The desired functionality cannot be easily implemented on the
   Query/Table level. Hence I've implemented it on the Form/Report
   level. Personally, I could see no way in theory to implement it on
   the Query/Table level, but I'm certain there are VBA gurus out there
   who can do anything.
3. Designers can use a Combo Box for each desired field in the
   many-to-many relationship. This gurantees no redundant entries. Then
   to add new entries VBA code has to be added to the "On Not In List"
   property of the Combo Box. See link above.

Hope this helps someone in the future. I know I was happy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if this is the answer that solved your issue, then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the Example from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) 
when you do your inner join it grabs information from both tables where any column Matches.
I assume that there are other columns in both Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a cross-reference table would join Table1 and Table2 like:

```
SELECT Table1.Name1, Table2.Name2
FROM ((Table1 INNER JOIN TableRef ON Table1.ID1 = TableRef.ID1) INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID2 = TableRef.ID2)
```

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Table1.Name1, Table2.Name2
FROM ((Table1 INNER JOIN TableRef ON Table1.ID1 = TableRef.ID1) INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID2 = TableRef.ID2)
```

Comment: The query I have above was created by Access using the query builder. I see that syntactically your code is different, but don't they perform equivalent queries? Granted I think yours is easier to read.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have a select query adding rows to your database.  That is not at all clear.  Select simply displays rows.  Anyway, I just edited my answer to show how DISTINCTROW can be used to reduce the results of the select statement down to unique rows.

Comment: MS Access 2010 provides abilities via the DataSheet View of the query, which allows users to enter records via the query, not simply view the results of the query.

Comment: Ahhh.  In that case, yes, your answer above is correct.  Never allow data entry directly via a query object.  Unless you don't care at all about the existing data.